# The price $535.90 we see as $535number_format_decimal_point90

Tags: google-translate

Please take a look attached screenshots. Only in english version price shows  ok as number, but other language «dot» before decimal is translated, like attached files instead of $535.90 we see $535number_format_decimal_point90
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhWtI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzUxw.png)

Comment: This is like asking "Here's a photo of my car, can you fix it?" We need to see the engine, the clutch, the brakes etc, not a photo of the exterior.

Comment: And how did you call Google Translate? Please show some code.

Comment: Also, I suspect this isn't code-related at all, instead you're using Google Translate, inputting a link to your site and then get that result. In this case, this is the wrong site for your question most likely, and I would probably ask on [webapps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) to start with.

Comment: Share the code.